# javascript hide show element checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have 8 check boxes, only one of these are checked by default.

When you click the unchecked ones twice the table(that the checkboxes are linked too) hide.

Ideally i need the unchecked ones to be hidden by default and the checked one to be shown by default. Then show then checked etc.

Here is the javascript code

```
function showhide(el, target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = el.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

And here is the html

```
<th><input onclick="showhide(this, '1')" type="checkbox"> 1 </th>
<td><input onclick="showhide(this, '3')" type="checkbox" checked> 3 </td>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(target)` here target should be id attribute of your input element.

Comment: isn't target being defined by the onclick?

Comment: Maybe a jsfiddle example with your code would be easier to fix ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is to set the default display

```js
function showhide(el) {
  document.getElementById(el.dataset.target).style.display = el.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
}

function showhideclick() {
  showhide(this);
}

var checks = document.getElementsByClassName('showhide'),
  chk;
for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++) {
  showhide(checks[i]);
  checks[i].addEventListener('click', showhideclick, i)
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <th><input class="showhide" data-target="1" type="checkbox"/> 1 </th>
  <td><input class="showhide" data-target="3" type="checkbox" checked/> 3 </td>
</tr>

<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bj5c533b/3/

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes don't have an id, your HTML should look like

```
 <th><input onclick="showhide(this, '1')" type="checkbox" id="1"> 1 </th>
 <td><input onclick="showhide(this, '3')" type="checkbox" id="3"> 3 </td>
```

Comment: `When you click the unchecked ones twice the table(that the checkboxes are linked too) hide` I think OP wants to hide other element but that's really poorly asked question

Comment: Oh didnt realize that. Too bad I cant downvote yet